# Minimization problem solving and its step limits

Tags: python, numpy, memory-optimization

I am trying to solve the following minimization problem:

$$
\min\lvert\lvert{x}\rvert\rvert_1 + \beta\lvert\lvert{x}\rvert\rvert^2_2 s.t. \sum_{m = 1}^M (y - \lvert{c}^{H} . x\rvert^2)^2 \le \epsilon
$$

- `x`: my unknown value (input) with complex elements and known size, here (4x1)
- `y`: the output vector (known)
- `c`: a 'skaling' vector

I am very new to this so my approach may seem basic. I simply loop over all combination of `c` (non-redundant) and according to the computed minimization value and condition I update my results.

My questions are the following:

- Is this correct and is there a better approach to this?
- This code fails with a small step due to the huge size of combinations, so how can I solve that?

```
from itertools import combinations
from random import randint
import numpy as np 

def deg2rad(phase):
    return round(((phase*3.14)/180),3)

def excitation(amplitude, phase):
    return complex(round(amplitude * (np.cos(deg2rad(phase))),3), round(amplitude*(np.sin(deg2rad(phase))),3))

def compute_subject_equation_result(x):
    M            = 12
    difference   = []
    y            = [randint(10, 20) for i in range(M)]

    for m in range(0, M):      
        c  = np.array([randint(0, 9), randint(10,20), randint(0, 9), randint(0,20)]).reshape(4,1)
        ch = c.conjugate().T
        eq  = (y[m] - (abs(np.dot(ch, x))[0])**2)**2
        difference.append(eq**2)
    return round(sum(difference)[0], 3)

def compute_main_equation_result(x, beta):
    norm1  = np.linalg.norm(x,1)
    norm2  = np.linalg.norm(x,2)
    return round(norm1 + beta*(norm2**2), 3)

def optimize(x, min_x, min_phi_x):
    min_result      = 10**25

    # compute the optimization formals and check for the min value
    main_equation_result    = compute_main_equation_result(c, beta)
    subject_equation_result = compute_subject_equation_result(c)

    # update min value if min detected'  
    if subject_equation_result < epsilon and main_equation_result < min_result:
        min_result = main_equation_result
        min_x      = x
        min_phi_x  = phx        
    return min_x, min_phi_x

# initialization
phases    = [alpha for alpha in range(0, 361, 90)]
beta      = 1
epsilon   = 10**25
min_x     = np.array([])
min_phi_x = np.array([])

phases_combinations = [list(comb) for comb in combinations(phases, 4)]

# start checking all combinations
for phx in  phases_combinations:
    phi1, phi2, phi3, phi4 = phx[0], phx[1], phx[2], phx[3]       
    # build the hypothesis for the excitations vector c 
    c = np.array([ excitation(1, phi1), excitation(1, phi2), excitation(1, phi3), excitation(1, phi4) ]).T.reshape(4,1)
    min_x, min_phi_x = optimize(c, min_x, min_phi_x)
    print('    --------------------------------------------------')
    print('-----> new_min_c     = ', list(min_x))
    print('-----> new_min_phi_c = ', min_phi_x)
```

Remark: When trying `phases = [alpha for alpha in range(0, 361, 1)]` I get a "memory error". I can avoid using a higher step. However I am not sure about my approach in general nor of the step change effect on the accuracy.